# IntelliJ: class variable javadoc to be inserted on getter/setter generation

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have the following code in a Java file:

```
/** Person's name. */
private String person;
```

When I go to the Generate menu and ask it to generate a "Getter and Setter", one of the options there is to pick a Getter template and a Setter template.

I wanted to copy/modify one of those template to create a Javadoc comment right above the getter/setter to copy the Javadoc that's already written on the declared variable to the method.

How do I reference that Javadoc comment?

This is the template that's there by default:

```
#set($paramName = $helper.getParamName($field, $project))
#if($field.modifierStatic)
static ##
#end
void
set$StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention( 
   $StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, 
       $project)))($field.type $paramName) {
#if ($field.name == $paramName)
  #if (!$field.modifierStatic)
    this.##
  #else
    $classname.##
  #end
#end
$field.name = $paramName;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to copy JavaDoc from the field to the method using the template. It could be implemented as a feature (like there is already one for copying JavaDoc for Override methods).

Note that in the IDE when you invoke documentation for the getter/setter that doesn't have JavaDoc, IntelliJ IDEA [should get it](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-60161) from the field automatically.